# browse site with domain instead of IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, iis

I'm very beginner(Comport me!) I have a windows server 2008 with nothing. i must up a ASP.Net site . Now i added a role to server(Web Server) and copied my files to wwwroot. Hitherto everything is OK and i browse my site very well(also when i type the IP in a web-browser, my site is loaded).

Now i want to browse my site with a domain name(like example-domain.com). but i don't how to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to lrosa, once you purchase your domain you'll likely need to purchase an extra add on to be able to manually manage your DNS.

Once you've done that, you can create 2 A records (one blank, one www) that point to your server's IP address.

Ensure your headers are correct in IIS (port 80, example-domain.com) and you should be ready to rock and roll.

IF you receive a "Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)" error, there is something wrong with your headers.

EDIT : http://www.iisanswers.com/dns_for_iis.htm may be of some assistance to you

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this with DNS.

You can do one or more of this:

- edit %SystemRoot%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts, put ip and name and restart your browser (on WinXP you have to type NBTSTAT -R with CAPITAL R)
- configure the DNS server you are using and add the zone/host
- register the name online and wait some hours